# Word for what you call yourself

Tags: single-word-requests

What words or phrases would you use to introduce someone by a nickname they've chosen? Say I want to introduce Dr. Samuels (who introduces herself as Susie-Q) to Dr. Smith. I can't call my superior Susie-Q without mentioning that the nickname wasn't my idea. Is there a word for someone's chosen form of address?

Comment: You can just say, "This is Dr. Samuels, but she likes go by 'Susie-Q'."

Comment: @Jim Please phrase your answer in the form of an answer.

Comment: @AlexTrebek- Wow. How long has it been since you were able to say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [alias](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Alias): (from TFD)

> - otherwise called. “Simpson alias Smith.
> - an assumed name

- Dr. Samuels, alias Susie Q.

also [pseudonym](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pseudonym)  (in case of a writer for instance)

> - A fictitious name, especially a pen name.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the nickname at the end, after a pause, generously garnished with a smile. If you are close/ informal enough, you could add "to us all" as well.

"Mr. Abraham Lincoln, :-) Abe (to us all)"

When introducing oneself, "to you" is the familiar way to go.

Comment: Yes, but if that is the case..the question appers to be off-topic..we are talking about good manners rather than language..and BOP also.

Comment: Sorry. I typed before I read.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pause as a verbal colon

> This is Dr. Samuels [pause] Suzie-Q.

Personal introductions are usually conducted with glances and gestures toward the person being introduced, further clarifying that the name and nickname are both attibuted to that individual.

**Note:** The gist of this answer was earlier offered by @Kris, (which I overlooked). Please see that answer.